# Can't direct into a route onclick with value with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have to add date value when i click hyperlink into my route, so i add like this:

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tanggal Awal:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Lahir" name="tglawal" id="tglawal">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tanggal Akhir:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Lahir" name="tglakhir" id="tglakhir">
        </div>

          <a href="" onclick="location.href='/cetaklaporanpasien/'+document.getElementById('tglawal').value + '/' + document.getElementById('tglakhir').value " class="btn btn-block btn-primary border-0" style="background-color: #6998AB">Cetak</a>
    </div>
```

My Route:

```
    Route::get('/cetaklaporanpasien/{tglawal}/{tglakhir}', 'LaporanController@cetakLaporanPasien')->name('cetaklaporanpasien');
```

But it's doesn't directing into my route. So, how to add laravel route with parameter in onclick?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<button>` instead of `<a>`

So it will be like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="(your link)">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be considering to use blade template as it is laravel standart templating.

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tanggal Awal:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Lahir" name="tglawal" id="tglawal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tanggal Akhir:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Lahir" name="tglakhir" id="tglakhir">
    </div>

      <a href="" onclick="cetakLaporan" class="btn btn-block btn-primary border-0" style="background-color: #6998AB">Cetak</a>
</div>
<script>
  let tglawal = document.getElementById('tglawal').value;
  let tglakhir = document.getElementById('tglakhir').value;
  function cetakLaporan(){
   location.href = `/cetaklaporanpasien/${tglawal}/${tglakhir}` 
  }
</script>
```